# How to go about constructing turing machines for specific languages?

Tags: automata, turing-machines, formal-languages

so far I have come across two types of languages. Languages where there is a strict format such as

L = {a^n b^n c^n | n >= 1}

This language it's strict for example a's will always come before b's etc.

the other type I've come across is languages where it can be any order.

L = {a,b}* where number of a's > number of b's

this language can be any order of a's and b's its not stuck in place.

[For the languages that are structured this machine conveys the general idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvpbS.png)

but I am having trouble finding the pattern for machines where it can be any order of characters.

For example

L = {a,b,c}* | a's are equal to the minimum of b and c

What is the pattern for those languages? and what are some really helpful techniques to design these?

Comment: For reasons similar to why the Halting Problem exists, there is no general approach to solve all problems. If there were, you could pass in the requirements for a machine that finds out whether a given machine halts on a given input, and the general approach would result in machine H, which is impossible. A Turing Machine specification is software, and there is no general solution for writing software that solves all problems, and similarly there is no general solution for specifying Turing Machines. You have to think about the problem and come up with a solution on your own.

Comment: I know, but for the examples above there seems to be a general structure. for just those types of languages. Do you possibly have any idea how to go about creating TM's as in some techinques? like writing out accepted/rejected strings. etc.

Comment: I would approach it in a similar manner to trying to approach it in conventional programming languages: subdivide the parts into manageable pieces. Such as a piece that counts a specific character, a piece that finds the minimum of two counts and a piece that invokes the other pieces in the correct order.

Comment: To reiterate what Welbog said: approach it like writing any other program. TMs are simply another programming language to learn how to write programs in; general rules, like reusable code, separation of concerns, etc. are all applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Your example of #a > #b is a classical one for a context-free language, which is recognized by a pushdown automaton. These devices only move once along the input and have a push-down store (stack). The basic idea is to put an a on the stack for every a you read in the input; for a b you remove one. Find a way to handle prefixes where you have more b than a. Then you accept exactly if you have some a left on the stack after reading the entire input.

This is easily implemented in a Turing Machine if you are allowed auxiliary tapes. Just use one as a stack. When more numbers are involved like in your last example, use more auxiliary tapes.

If you have no auxiliary tapes, you have to do more running around with the read-write-head. For example use a structure:

```
input%stack1%stack2%stack3%
```

where % is a separating symbol that does not occur anywhere else. Another option is an approach that does not part from the push-down automaton: marking symbols. For example for #a > #b:

1. mark the first unmarked b
2. mark the first unmarked a
3. if there are unmarked b left, go to 1.; else check whether there is at least one unmarked a left - if so accept, otherwise reject

These are two standard techniques that you can use for these counting problems. Of course, as people have commented already, for every given language you have to adapt your solution.